# read event never triggered, using libevent

Tags: epoll, libevent

I just write an echo server using libevent， but it seems that the read event is never triggered. The code is:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <event.h>
#include <event2/event.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

static short ListenPort = 19999;
static long ListenAddr = INADDR_ANY;//任意地址，值就是0
static int   MaxConnections = 1024;

static int ServerSocket;
static struct event ServerEvent;

int SetNonblock(int fd)
{
    int flags;
    if ((flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL)) == -1) {
            return -1;
    }

    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) == -1) {
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void ServerRead(int fd, short ev, void *arg)
{
    //1)when telnet on 1999 and send a string,this never prints,help!
    printf("client readble\n");
    fflush(stdout);
            struct client *client = (struct client *)arg;
    u_char buf[8196];
    int len, wlen;

    len = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (len == 0) {
            printf("disconnected\n");
            close(fd);
            event_del(&ServerEvent);
            free(client);
            return;
    } else if (len < 0) {
            printf("socket fail %s\n", strerror(errno));
            close(fd);
            event_del(&ServerEvent);
            free(client);
            return;
    }

    wlen = write(fd, buf, len);//1)client str never echo back
    if (wlen < len) {
            printf("not all data write back to client\n");
    }
}

void ServerWrite(int fd, short ev, void *arg)
{
//2)to be simple,let writer do nothing
/*  if(!arg)
    {
            printf("ServerWrite err!arg null\n");
            return;
    }
    int len=strlen(arg);
    if(len <= 0)
    {
            printf("ServerWrite err!len:%d\n",len);
            return;
    }
            int wlen = write(fd, arg, len);
        if (wlen<len) {
                printf("not all data write back to client!wlen:%d len:%d \n",wlen,len);
        }
*/
    return;
}


void ServerAccept(int fd, short ev, void *arg)
{
    int cfd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    int yes = 1;

    cfd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrlen);
    if (cfd == -1) {
    //3)this prints ok
            printf("accept(): can not accept client connection");
            return;
    }
    if (SetNonblock(cfd) == -1) {
            close(cfd);
            return;
    }

    if (setsockopt(cfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &yes, sizeof(yes)) == -1) {
            printf("setsockopt(): TCP_NODELAY %s\n", strerror(errno));
            close(cfd);
            return;
    }

    event_set(&ServerEvent, cfd, EV_READ | EV_PERSIST, ServerRead, NULL);
    event_set(&ServerEvent, cfd, EV_WRITE| EV_PERSIST, ServerWrite,NULL);
    event_add(&ServerEvent, NULL);

    printf("Accepted connection from %s \n", (char *)inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr));
}
int NewSocket(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in sa;

    ServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (ServerSocket == -1) {
            printf("socket(): can not create server socket\n");
            return -1;
    }
    if (SetNonblock(ServerSocket) == -1) {
            return -1;
    }

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_port = htons(ListenPort);
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(ListenAddr);

    if (bind(ServerSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa)) == -1) {
            close(ServerSocket);
            printf("bind(): can not bind server socket");
            return -1;
    }

    if (listen(ServerSocket, MaxConnections) == -1) {
            printf("listen(): can not listen server socket");
            close(ServerSocket);
            return -1;
    }
    event_set(&ServerEvent, ServerSocket, EV_READ | EV_PERSIST, ServerAccept, NULL);
    if (event_add(&ServerEvent, 0) == -1) {
            printf("event_add(): can not add accept event into libevent");
            close(ServerSocket);
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int retval;
    event_init();
    retval = NewSocket();
    if (retval == -1) {
       exit(-1);
    }
    event_dispatch();
    return 0;
}
```

The server is tested using Telnet, but the client receives nothing.
The question details are posted as comments in the code above, at 1)、2)、3).
Can someone help me find out why the read event is never triggered?

Answer (score 0):

basically you should not set the accepted socket as EV_WRITE until you actually want to write to the socket. You are telling libevent "let me know when I can write to this socket", which is pretty much always. So ServerWrite is being called in a tight loop. In practice the only time you need EV_WRITE is if you are writing a buffer but all of the bytes are not written. You then need to save the unwritten portion of the buffer and use EV_WRITE to signal when the socket can be written to again.

Comment: thx，but what i want to know is why the serverread is never called?

Comment: you may talking about when to write an echo like  codes displied here:https://github.com/jasonish/libevent-examples/blob/master/echo-server/libevent_echosrv2.c

Comment: ServerRead is not being called because this is single threaded and ServerWrite is infinite looping. If you put a printf right at the beginning of ServerWrite you will see what I mean. If you search the github example for ev_write it will show you how to use buffers for writing